# Efficient method (maybe parallel method) to calculate a 256$\times$256 matrix?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

I want to calculate a matrix of shape 256$\times$256 as follows

```
ParallelTable[Tr[emat[[i]].IntegrateUnitaryHaar[UV.emat[[j]].ConjugateTranspose[UV],{u,15},{v,1}]]/16,{i,1,256},{j,1,256}]
```

where `emat[[i]]` is a matrix. I have already used `ParallelTable` to execute the code parallelly. But it seems the program is still very inefficient. I wonder if there are some more efficient methods to execute the code?

**Edit** Here is some more information about the code that I want to speed up. I create an `emat` to help me construct the target matrix. `emat` is defined as

```
emat=ConstantArray[0,{256,16,16}];
(*Calculate Bases*)
Do[emat[[(i-1)*64+(j-1)*16+(k-1)*4+l]]=KroneckerProduct[KroneckerProduct[KroneckerProduct[Subscript[\[Sigma], i],Subscript[\[Sigma], j]],Subscript[\[Sigma], k]],Subscript[\[Sigma], l]],{i,1,4},{j,1,4},{k,1,4},{l,1,4}];
```

where `Sigma` are pauli matrices defined as

```
Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] = ( {
   {0, 1},
   {1, 0}
  } ); Subscript[\[Sigma], 2] = ( {
   {0, -I},
   {I, 0}
  } ); Subscript[\[Sigma], 3] = ( {
   {1, 0},
   {0, -1}
  } ); Subscript[\[Sigma], 4] = ( {
   {1, 0},
   {0, 1}
  } );
```

Before creating the target matrix, I need some more materials I dubbed U and V matrices. Code as follows

```
U = Array[Subscript[u, #1, #2] &, {15, 15}];
V = Array[Subscript[v, #1, #2] &, {1, 1}];
UV = ArrayFlatten[{{V, 0}, {0, U}}];
changebasisu = IdentityMatrix[hilbertdim];
changebasisu[[1, 1]] = 1/Sqrt[2]; changebasisu[[1, 16]] = 1/Sqrt[2]; 
changebasisu[[16, 1]] = 1/Sqrt[2]; changebasisu[[16, 16]] = -1/Sqrt[2];
UV = changebasisu . UV . ConjugateTranspose[changebasisu];
```

Finally I can write the formula for the elements of the target matrix to be

```
ParallelTable[Tr[emat[[i]].IntegrateUnitaryHaar[UV.emat[[j]].ConjugateTranspose[UV],{u,15},{v,1}]]/16,{i,1,256},{j,1,256}]
```

where `IntegrateUnitaryHaar` is a function to [calculate integration with respect to the Haar measure on the unitary groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4244). To execute this function, you need to install a [related package](https://github.com/iitis/IntU) inside Mathematica and using code << IntU` inside Mathematica.

The execution result of `$Version` on my Mathematica is `13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)`.

I've tried to execute the following code to calculate only the **first line** of the target matrix, with `AbsoluteTiming` function as

```
ParallelDo[pmat[[1,j]]=Tr[emat[[1]].IntegrateUnitaryHaar[UV.emat[[j]].ConjugateTranspose[UV],{u,15},{v,1}]]/16,{j,1,256}];//AbsoluteTiming
```

The result is `{884.955,Null}` which is very slow!

Since I think every element in essence can be calculated in an absolutely uncorrelated way. So I really expect parallelly execute the code to dramatically slow down the running time. But I didn't solve it yet, is it I just didn't do it right?

The total code showing as follows(the code needs to download [the package](https://github.com/iitis/IntU) and then install it inside Mathematica. I temporarily don't know how to add it directly to the code below.)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Subscript[\[Sigma], 1] = ( {
   {0, 1},
   {1, 0}
  } ); Subscript[\[Sigma], 2] = ( {
   {0, -I},
   {I, 0}
  } ); Subscript[\[Sigma], 3] = ( {
   {1, 0},
   {0, -1}
  } ); Subscript[\[Sigma], 4] = ( {
   {1, 0},
   {0, 1}
  } );
emat = ConstantArray[0, {256, 16, 16}];
(*Calculate Bases*)
Do[emat[[(i - 1)*64 + (j - 1)*16 + (k - 1)*4 + l]] = 
   KroneckerProduct[
    KroneckerProduct[
     KroneckerProduct[Subscript[\[Sigma], i], Subscript[\[Sigma], j]],
      Subscript[\[Sigma], k]], Subscript[\[Sigma], l]], {i, 1, 4}, {j,
    1, 4}, {k, 1, 4}, {l, 1, 4}];
(*target matrix*)
pmat = ConstantArray[0, {256, 256}];
(*Prepare package for doing haar integral*)
<< IntU`;
(*Routine to do haar integral*)
U = Array[Subscript[u, #1, #2] &, {15, 15}];
V = Array[Subscript[v, #1, #2] &, {1, 1}];
UV = ArrayFlatten[{{V, 0}, {0, U}}];
changebasisu = IdentityMatrix[16];
changebasisu[[1, 1]] = 1/Sqrt[2]; changebasisu[[1, 16]] = 1/Sqrt[2]; 
changebasisu[[16, 1]] = 1/Sqrt[2]; changebasisu[[16, 16]] = -1/Sqrt[2];
UV = changebasisu . UV . ConjugateTranspose[changebasisu];
pmat = ParallelTable[
    pmat[[i, j]] = 
     Tr[emat[[i]] . 
        IntegrateUnitaryHaar[
         UV . emat[[j]] . ConjugateTranspose[UV], {u, 15}, {v, 1}]]/
      16, {i, 1, 256}, {j, 1, 256}]; // AbsoluteTiming
pmat
```

Comment: To make the before/after comparison more effective you can include timing information from `AbsoluteTiming`. Also, include the output of `$Version` to your post. What type of entries does `emat` have? Please include `emat` and `UV`. In short, please present a minimal example and include definitions.

Comment: @Syed Thanks for pointing out those. I edited my post.

Comment: You are recomputing `IntegrateUnitaryHaar[UV.emat[[j]].ConjugateTranspose[UV],{u,15},{v,1}]` for every value of `i` instead of [memoizing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html) it.

Comment: Use sparse Pauli matrices for speed: `Clear[σ, emat]; σ[i_] := σ[i] = SparseArray[PauliMatrix[i]]; emat[i_Integer, j_Integer, k_Integer, l_Integer] := emat[i, j, k, l] = KroneckerProduct[σ[i], σ[j], σ[k], σ[l]]` will give you memoized, sparse, quick access to the `emat` values without forcing a pre-compute.

Comment: Can you please edit your post so that the code can be copy-pasted into a notebook and will actually run? Please don't expect people to piece it together by themselves.

Comment: @Roman I'll do it right now. But the code relies on installing a package in the link I gave. I'm not sure if I can also add it to the code. PS thanks for your two technical suggestions. I think it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally finish the calculation in finite time. The method is based on the comments of @Roman. Codes showing as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"];
\[Sigma][i_] := \[Sigma][i] = SparseArray[PauliMatrix[i]];
emat = SparseArray[ConstantArray[0, {256, 16, 16}]];
Do[emat[[(i - 1)*64 + (j - 1)*16 + (k - 1)*4 + l]] = 
   KroneckerProduct[\[Sigma][i], \[Sigma][j], \[Sigma][k], \[Sigma][
     l]], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}, {k, 1, 4}, {l, 1, 4}];
(*Prepare package for doing haar integral*)
<< IntU`;
(*Routine to do haar integral*)
U = Array[Subscript[u, #1, #2] &, {15, 15}];
V = Array[Subscript[v, #1, #2] &, {1, 1}];
UV = ArrayFlatten[{{V, 0}, {0, U}}];
changebasisu = IdentityMatrix[16];
changebasisu[[1, 1]] = 1/Sqrt[2]; changebasisu[[1, 16]] = 1/Sqrt[2]; 
changebasisu[[16, 1]] = 1/Sqrt[2]; changebasisu[[16, 16]] = -1/Sqrt[2];
UV = changebasisu . UV . ConjugateTranspose[changebasisu];
integralemat[j_Integer] := 
  integralemat[j] = 
   IntegrateUnitaryHaar[
    UV . emat[[j]] . ConjugateTranspose[UV], {u, 15}, {v, 1}];
pmat = SparseArray[ConstantArray[0, {256, 256}]];
Do[pmat[[i, j]] = Tr[emat[[i]] . integralemat[j]]/16, {i, 1, 256}, {j,
     1, 256}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

The result of `AbsoluteTiming` function is  `{890.54, Null}`. But this time it's the time for the total target matrix instead of one row.

Comment: I tried your first code and found out that your emat is nothing else but 
Flatten[TensorProduct[#,#,#]&[PauliMatrix[{1,2,3}], 3]

Answer (score 1):

I tried your first code and found out that your emat tensor  is nothing else but
Flatten[TensorProduct[#,#,#]&[PauliMatrix[{1,2,3}], 3]

The execution  observed via task manager in Windows is showing an excessive use of the virtual memory on the disk.

I have a SSD as system disk and a backup HDD. The HDD is used and the prediction of Timing  shown by Parallel  amounts to hours.

The simple reason seems to be the unbeleavable amount of symbolic expression trees written and read from and to disk for any tiny step.

If RAM memory  holds the complete execution tree there is a time factor of 0.1 with respect to a SSD depending on the interface.